# prevent <li> from breaking across lines

Tags: html, css

I have a UL, inside a div where I have set the width of, DIV, UL and LI. I want overflow to scroll if there is any, so I set overflow to auto.  However, I can't seem to prevent the LI from breaking across lines when it is too wide.  Here is the css I am using:

```
/* id of the containing div */
#ul-container {
    width: 325px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #4297d7;
    overflow: auto;
}

           /* this is the id if the ul*/
#selectable {
    width: 300px;
    height: 75px;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
    background: #ccc;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
    background: #4297d7;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

The overflow property in the li doesn't seem to do anything. When I put it on the div, I get the horizontal scroll whether I need it or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#ul-container{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

`white-space: nowrap` will prevent the children (the li's) from going to a new line.

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AyIyaPO/1/edit)**